# Convert number of weeks in decimal to fraction

Tags: javascript, math, decimal, fractions

I ma struggling with this mathematical-based query.

I have the difference in seconds between two dates, and would like to convert the number of seconds to a fraction. I have the decimal working well, but am struggling to figure out how I can convert this value to a fraction.

So, for example, the number of weeks difference between the two timestamps is 4.285714285714286. I would like to represent this as `4 2/7`.

Can anyone suggest the most efficient way to achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: Is it always going to be effectively weeks and days that you want? If so then you can just take the decimal part of the number of weeks and multiply by 7 and round. This assumes you always want something over 7. If your number on the bottom of the fraction can change then it is much harder...

Comment: Arbritrary fractions or just sevenths?

Comment: They will always be sevenths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand your question, so this could be a very naive answer. If yes, just says so.

```
var
  a = new Date(2011, 12, 31),
  b = new Date(2011, 12, 1),
  weekMilliSeconds = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  fraction = (a - b)  / weekMilliSeconds,
  weeks = Math.floor(fraction),
  days = Math.round((fraction - weeks) * 7);

console.log(
  weeks + ' ' + days + '/7'  // => 4 2/7
);
```

Comment: @BenM In what way *false*. You have to be a little more descriptive.